# count ocurrences and creating a column based on the count in Python

Tags: python, pandas

a silly question for most of you.

I have this list:

```
      In      DT_INI      DT_FIM     Status         Description jobName
0  IN100  01/01/2022  01/02/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_01   XX_01
1  IN200  01/02/2022  01/03/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_01   XX_01
2  IN300  01/03/2022  01/04/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_02   XX_02
```

I need to count how many Ins a jobName has in this list, get this count and populate a new column named `Qt_Ins`.

it should looks like this:

```
      In   jobName     DT_INI      DT_FIM      Status      Description Qt_Ins
0     IN100 XX_01 01/01/2022  01/02/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_01      2
1     IN200 XX_01 01/02/2022  01/03/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_01      2
2     IN300 XX_02 01/03/2022  01/04/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_02      1
```

Could you guys help me again?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: so far no, because I got stuck in what to do,its not a matter to simply count ocurrences, I need to count and also get this value and create a new column in my list,...=/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """      In      DT_INI      DT_FIM     Status         Description  jobName
0  IN100  01/01/2022  01/02/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_01   XX_01
1  IN200  01/02/2022  01/03/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_01   XX_01
2  IN300  01/03/2022  01/04/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_02   XX_02"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(s), "\s\s+", engine="python")
```

You can use `groupby` with `nunique`:

```
# Store columns
cols = list(df.columns)
df.set_index("jobName", inplace=True)
# Do the group by
df["Qt_Ins"] = df.groupby("jobName")["In"].nunique()
# Re-order columns
df = df.reset_index()[cols + ["Qt_Ins"]]
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
      In      DT_INI      DT_FIM     Status         Description jobName  Qt_Ins
0  IN100  01/01/2022  01/02/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_01   XX_01       2
1  IN200  01/02/2022  01/03/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_01   XX_01       2
2  IN300  01/03/2022  01/04/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_02   XX_02       1
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm trying this solution, but getting a error in the first step:

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(s), "\s\s+", engine="python")

what does meand the "\s\s+", engine="python" ? the "s" would be the list created by you?

Comment: You have a dataframe right?

Comment: I have the list mentioned, which has a different name... I tried replacing only the list name:

df_test = pd.read_table(StringIO(list_data), "\s\s+", engine="python")

which gave me the below error message:

TypeError : initial_value must be str or None,not list

that's why I asked about the block "\s\s+", engine="python".Not sure if the s is the list created or something else

Comment: Can you post the variable `list_data`?

Comment: it is first list posted in my question, basically your list named s. It was a dataframe that I transformed into a list due another operation. thats why you have 0,1 and 2 as values for the first column

Comment: What is the data type of the first element in the list?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247349/discussion-between-cosmic-inquiry-and-gfernandes).